# Halmos Measure Theory section 5

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

**Th5.B** E is a class of sets. $R_o (E)$ is the ring generated by E. Any set in $R_o (E)$ can be covered by a finite union of sets in E.

The proof: The class of all sets that can be covered by a finite union of sets in E is a ring. **Since this ring contains E**, it also contains $R_o(E)$.

My question is: why does the ring referred to in the proof contain the whole class E? What if the class is the uncountable union of some sets, can it still be contained in the ring? Is the proof saying that any class of sets E is contained in the class of all sets that can be covered by a finite union of sets in the class, even if the class is, say, uncountable?

This is my first question here, so if I don't comply with forum requirements, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A \in E$. Then the singleton $\{A\}$ is a finite subset of $E$ and $A = \bigcup\{A\}$, so $A$ is equal to (and therefore covered by) a finite union of sets in $E$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see your point. Probably digging a little too deep but, do you need the Axiom of Choice to argue like this for an uncountable set?

Comment: Nope, the all the steps are there and AC is not needed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again.

Comment: @Paul Sure.$\ \ \ $